# read content of list item attachment in SPD workflow and convert to base64 string

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, attachments

I need to write a workflow that reads the content of attachment of a list item, convert it to base64 encoded string and then invoke a custom REST service.

I know I can access `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MyList')/items(" + id + ")/AttachmentFiles` and get the server relative URL of the attachment from result.

But I'm not sure how to get the contents of that file and convert it to base64 string.

**Update:**

I've found the following REST API that allows me to read the content of the attachment:

```
/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('server relative URL of attachment from earlier call')/$value
```

Now the question remains that how to get this content in base64 format?

Comment: Would you be able to post the steps on how to accomplish this in SPD. I am desperately in need to convert files to base64.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but maybe my answer can help people with the same problem.

I was struggling with this issue also.

I replaced the web request of the document content (`/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('server relative URL of attachment from earlier call')/$value`) from the workflow to a .NET service.

In the service I converted the byte array to a base64 string.